probleme install nuitka in my python download in web
I can't install nuitka on my python installed on the internet, version 3.10.0.
I've been trying for a while now on commands, the commands given on the nuitka site but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to install the nuitka now but pip "not found". I tried several non-functional commands. Help for download nuitka in my python 3.10.0.
My problem is that I don't have pip from what I saw, but pip doesn't want to install, I downloaded the pip in zip and put it in the python folder.enter image description here
enter image description here
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/2hrEv5M6.png

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

error on image shows you solution after text Usage: - you have to use python -m pip ... - not pip -m ..., not pippython -m ..., not pip python -m ...

Please put the whole error message in the post, maybe there are more helpful informations like @furas already said. Probably you should try to install it like this: pip install Nuitka

sThis does not work, because it is not the python from the Microsoft store so it does not recognize pip.

Ok, then post please the full error message

cela ne fonctionne pas , car ce n'est pas le python du microsoft store donc sa reconnait pas pip .

Please use English, also in the comments.

Ok im sorry use english

Then you have another problem! You said there is an error with the package, but it seems like an error that you haven't installed pip (correctly). My tips for you:

use english
send the full error message
open a new post with these changes


how can I install pip, I only installed python myself

I will repeat - see your image and read after word Usage:  - python.exe -m pip install -U nuitka And you what to use directly pip then DON'T use -m - pip install -U nuitka

I just found it, I think I need to install pip first

What does not work with pip install Nuitka? Take care about using N instead of n ...

What about installation from source?

We don't see the commands that you type, we don't see the resulting output that those commands produce. You should [edit] your question and show the commands and output (just copy-paste) of what you have tried. Because currently, we're just guessing what you are doing. As a result, you'll get different suggestions, possibly conflicting, possibly incorrect and so on.

I can't install pip

Bro read the messages... Use instead of pip install [packagename] python.exe -m pip install -U Nuitka

if you don't have pip then you have to download script get-pip.py from official documentation Installing Packages - Python Packaging User Guide - and later run python.exe get-pip.py

@zlElo While not in a text form, one of the images shows that the OP did use python -m pip install -U Nuitka, and got a "no module named pip" error. Bro, read the images.

can I have your discord to show you the installation problems?

show it for all people - put it as text in question, not image.

OP, you forgot to download get-pip.py, as mentioned above; it's not there by default, you have to download it yourself.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I can't install it puts me on a page, I have difficulty understanding and otherwise I installed in zip and it doesn't work

OK ... so install it from source: python setup.py install ( https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka )

As I read from the downloading tutorial, I saw this:

Windows
The MSI installers are discontinued as Python has
deprecated their support for them, as well as Windows 10 making it
harder to users to install them. Using the PyPI installation is
recommended on Windows.

The site said that you should use PyPI (pip) but you said that your pip doesn't work, I think you haven't install pip (check again), so install it here.
If your pip is having some other problems, you should find out how to fix it somewhere else.
However, if you found out some way to fix your pip, you can install nuitka by the tutorial here.
# Stable version
python -m pip install -U nuitka

# Develop version
python -m pip install -U "https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/archive/develop.zip"

If you're using Python3, remember to change python to py
